# Getting the is-a relationship of an object dynamically

Tags: inheritance, types, dart

I'm working on a fork of the jsonx dart to json serialization library to address some of the issues I've had with it. I've run into the problem of how to dynamically check if an object is-a Type.

For example, this dart code works fine:

```
var s = new Set<String>();
print(s is Set); // true
```

But this does not:

```
Type t = Set;
// outputs warning: the name t is not a type and cannot be 
// used in an 'is' expression
print(s is t);
```

(Full example: [dartpad link](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/1069fa61ace81c2448babaf2c249335e))

One workaround I've come up with is to have a lambda defined for each type I want to check, for example, replacing the `s is t` above with a call to a custom lambda such as: ([dartpad link](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/1234f657def5603011ad2c0eb3668f97))

```
var isSetType = (var to_check) => to_check is Set;
```

However it seems silly to have to create a lambda for each type I want to check dynamically.

In Java, I can do the following ([full example](https://gist.github.com/ahirschberg/21cdd9c05249463748d698c7217291dc)):

```
Class<?> t = Set.class;
Object s = new HashSet<String>();
System.out.println(t.isInstance(s)); // true
```

I'd like to be able to call a method similar to Java's Class.isInstance(Object), but the Type objects dart provides are [extremely bare](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.21.0/dart-core/Type-class.html). Is this just a limitation of the language in its current state, or is there an elegant way to check types dynamically? Using `.runtimeType` is not an option because `new Set().runtimeType == Set` is false. (That behavior is discussed by dart contributors in [this](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/11225#issuecomment-108376414) thread on github)

Comment: As soon as they add support for generic types for method at runtime you would be able to do something like that : `isInstance<T>(o) => o is T;`  <br />see [dart github](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/254)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you statically know the types you can use a generic class to test:

```dart
class InstanceTester<T> {
  bool isInstance(o) => o is T;
}

main(){
  var s = new Set<int>();
  print(new InstanceTester<Set>().isInstance(s));          // true
  print(new InstanceTester<Set<String>>().isInstance(s));  // false
  print(new InstanceTester<Set<int>>().isInstance(s));     // true
  print(new InstanceTester<Map>().isInstance(s));          // false
}
```